# Is Perforce's C++ P4API thread-safe?

Tags: c++, perforce

Simple question - is the C++ API provided by Perforce thread-safe? There is no mention of it in the documentation.

By "thread-safe" I mean for server requests from the client. Obviously there will be issues if I have multiple threads trying to set client names and such on the same connection.

But given a single connection object, can I have multiple threads fetching changelists, getting status, translating files through a p4 map, etc.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Late answer, but... From the [release notes](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r11.1/user/p4api.netnotes.txt) themselves:

> Known Limitations

```
      The Perforce client-server protocol is not designed to support
      multiple concurrent queries over the same connection. For this
      reason, multi-threaded applications using the C++ API or the
      derived APIs (P4API.NET, P4Perl, etc.) should ensure that a
      separate connection is used for each thread or that only one
      thread may use a shared connection at a time.
```

It does not look like the client object has thread affinity, so in order to share a connection between threads, one just has to use a mutex to serialize the calls.

Comment: As a side note, the Perforce admins at my shop recommended we establish a new connection when we need one instead of keeping the same one open and reusing it among threads: open connections use up PIDs and other resources on the instance.

Answer (score 4):

If the documentation doesn't mention it, then it is not safe.

Making something thread-safe in any sense is often difficult and may result in a performance penalty because of the addition of locks. It wouldn't make sense to go through the trouble and then not mention it in the documentation.

Comment: That's a good point. Though on the performance front, given that the overwhelming cost of doing any query is going to be server response and network transfer time, I was thinking that the API would be as safe as possible. Still, if they don't mention it, it's better to assume it's not safe, as you say.